# how to use jquery each loop in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops

I need output like below code, where each set of div is coming trough ajax as  follows, i am getting div id dynamic as slide1, slide2 via jquery  each function. **assume that there is no anchor tag at start so how can i get href="#pix1", href="#pix2" ? every time href value is increasing by 1** thanks help is really appreciated

```
<div id="slide1">
        <ol>
            <li class="firstlist"><a href="#"><b>start</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix1"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic1.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix2"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic2.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix3"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic3.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix4"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic4.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix5"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic5.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix6"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic6.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix7"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic7.jpg"></a></li>
            <li class="lastlist"><a href="#"><b>last</b></a></li>
        </ol>
    </div> <div id="slide2">
        <ol>
            <li class="firstlist"><a href="#"><b>start</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix2"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic2.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix3"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic3.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix4"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic4.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix5"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic5.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix6"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic6.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix7"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic7.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pix8"><img src="images/thumbs/accesories/pic8.jpg"></a></li>
            <li class="lastlist"><a href="#"><b>last</b></a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

and in jquery i am tring something like as follows

---

```
 $("div").each(function(si){
        var slideindex = si+1                               
         $(this).attr('id', 'slide'+slideindex);    
    //I am successful here to get div id slide 0, slide1                
                                    });  


  $('div ol li a').each(function() {

//how should i code here           
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(this).attr('href');
```

Inside the loop that is

Comment: mhhh... but every time how should i add 1 in href :-(

Comment: @edwin6523: exactly as you did in the first `.each`, by adding an index argument to the `each` function.

Answer (score 0):

check this demo.

http://www.balam.in/personal/stackoverflow/each_example.html

You have already done that for div. For anchor, its the same. YOu just need to specify href attribute. Is that you are looking for?

```
$('div ol li a').each(function(i) {
         var anchorindex = i+1                               
         $(this).attr('href', '#pix'+anchorindex);           
    });
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i need href="#pix(x)" completely dynamic via jqery. assume that there is no href at start i want to add it via jquery also href value tooo